# [__NSCFString count]: Unrecognized selector

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, unrecognized-selector

I know this has been asked before, but there is no answer that I have found useful.

First off here is my code

```
// load the .csv file with all information about the track

            NSError *error;
            NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"csv" inDirectory:nil];

            NSString *datastring1 = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filepath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
            NSArray *datarow = [datastring1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r"];

            //fill arrays with the values from .csv file
            NSArray *data_seg = [datarow objectAtIndex:0]; //segment number
            NSArray *data_slength = [datarow objectAtIndex:1]; //strait length
            NSArray *data_slope = [datarow objectAtIndex:2]; //slope
            NSArray *data_cradius = [datarow objectAtIndex:3]; //circle radius
            NSArray *data_cangle = [datarow objectAtIndex:4]; //circle angle

            NSLog(@"%i", [data_seg count]);
```

Okay, so there is the code, and I read that is has something to do with autorelease, but I was not able to add a retain like `NSArray *data_seg = [[datarow objectAtIndex:0] retain]`

When I run the code, I get [__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9d1ad50

Any help is appreciated, I'm not good at programming, and I am very new.

Comment: Your code snippet only shows a single occurrence of 'count' method being called, and it's being called on something called 'bob_calgary_data_seg' which isn't in your code snippet. Did you mean to call count on datarow or one of the other NSArray instances?

Comment: I assume the problem is with bob_calgary_data_seg? that's the only thing using -count. The error is telling you that bob_calgary_data_seg is an NSString, but you think that it's something else (an NSArray perhaps?) since you're calling -count on it. Or you think it's an NSString, and then perhaps you want -length? I can't tell without knowing what bob_calgary_data_seg is.  Anyways, that's really your problem... the error seems a wee obtuse, but that's what it is.  So, figure out what you're doing with bob_calgary_data_seg and that should lead you in some direction.

Comment: @PaulDardeau Sorry, I meant data_seg, I edited the OP.

Comment: The message means you're using `count` on a NSString.  How is that not self-explanatory??  (Have you really examined the exception traceback to see where the error occurs?)

Comment: @HotLicks yes... I define it as an NSArray, that's why I'm confused.

Comment: How you "define" a pointer does not control (very much) the object class of the address stored in the pointer.  The object is *really* a string which you erroneously placed in an array pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

componentsSeparatedByString method returns an NSArray of NSString. Every item that you extract from datarow array is an NSString and an NSString doesn't respond to 'count'. Your code starting at //fill arrays is incorrect. Every objectAtIndex call will return an NSString*.

This is another way of saying that the datatype for data_seg is NSString* (not NSArray*).

Comment: Alright thank you! that clears up a lot. So what would I have to do to create a NSArray* data_seg?

Comment: You don't. `datarow` is an array of strings. When you get one object from the array you get an `NSString`. Why do you want it to be another array?

Comment: It appears that you're trying to parse a CSV file. Your first call to componentsSeparatedByString is splitting a file contents into a list of lines from the file, right? The next thing would be to iterate through all lines of the file and then call componentsSeparatedByString to split the line by ','. I think these are the main parts you're missing.

Comment: Yes, I did `NSString *data_segString = [datarow objectAtIndex:0];` and after `NSArray *data_seg = [data_segString componentsSeparatedByString:@","]` . This created an array :D

Answer (score 0):

With the corrected code snippet, the problem is because `data_seg` is a string, and `-count` is not a method of `NSString`. It seems you think `data_seg` is an `NSArray`.

Look at the documentation for `-[NSString componentsSeparatedByString:]` and see what it returns -- strings! So you get back an array of strings.  So what you want is:

```
NSString *data_seg = [datarow objectAtIndex:0]; //segment number
NSLog(@"my segment number is: %@", data_seg);
```

Comment: Actually, the `componentsSeparatedByString:` method is a method of `NSString`, not `NSArray`, and it returns an `NSArray`. That's not the problem. Though the code you posted is correct. It's the explanation before it that is incorrect.